# Django: How to know the the name of the URL that is attending a certain request

Tags: django, django-urls

I am working with Django 1.8.

I have fairly large and complex list of urls defined in several apps.

One of the requests I'm launching is not being dispatched by the URL that I want. Also, I don't even know which url is atending such a request.

So my question is: is there any way of knowing the name of the url that would attend a certain request?

Comment: Didn't get your question completely. But this request.url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `resolve` function to find out how Django is resolving your URL:

```
from django.urls import resolve
result = resolve('my_url')
```

This returns a ResolverMatch object which has attribute for the `url_name` that matched your URL and the `func` which it will be routed to.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.